# Django - Retrieve Data for 2 Separate Querysets On One Page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django, PyCharm 2018.3.7, Python 3.7, and Postgres.

Unfortunately, I do not understand how to display on one screenpage (Django form) the results for 2 separate querysets that need the same ID passed by a dynamic filter request (GET). There is a table/model (ASSIGNMENTS) with a One-To-Many relationship to another table/model (PRODUCTS).  The ID being passed is the ASSIGNMENTS.ID, which is the PK of ASSIGNMENTS and the FK of PRODUCTS.

I am not trying to join these 2 querysets.  I need the user to see the information for the ASSIGNMENT first and then below I want them to see all of the PRODUCTS that belong to that ASSIGNMENT.

I do not need to update/create data, so no POST is needed.  Only want to retrieve, GET, data that exists.

Below are the code for models.py, views.py, and templates.  It works perfect with just ASSIGNMENTS.

**MODELS.PY**

```
    class Assignments(models.Model):
        id = models.DecimalField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=0)    
        name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', unique=True, max_length=40)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name + ' ' + '(' + '#' + str(self.id) + ')'

        class Meta:
            ordering = 'name',
            db_table = 'ASSIGNMENTS'

    class Products(models.Model):
        id = models.DecimalField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, max_digits=11, decimal_places=0)  
        assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignments, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='productsfor_assignment', db_column='ASSIGNMENT_ID', blank=True, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=80)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name + ' ' + '(' + '#' + str(self.id) + ')'

        class Meta:
            ordering = 'name',
            db_table = 'PRODUCTS'
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
    def search_form(request):
        return render(request, 'assignments/search_form.html')

    def search(request):
        if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
            q = request.GET['q']
            assign = Assignments.objects.filter(id__icontains=q)
            return render(request, 'assignments/search_results.html',
                {'AssignmentsResults': assign, 'query': q})
        else:
        # if the query is empty, render the 'search_form html' template again.
        # display an error message in that template.  So, pass a template variable.
        # 'search_form html' will check for the 'error' variable
            return render(request, 'assignments/search_form.html', {'error': True})
```

**TEMPLATE 'search_form.html'**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    <br><br>
    <h1> Assignment ID Search Form </h1>
    <br><br>
        {% if error %}
            <p style="color: red;">Please submit a search term.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="/search/" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter ID here ...">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

    <p>
        Page last updated: {{ last_updated|date:'D d F Y' }}
    </p>
    {% endblock content %}
```

**TEMPLATE 'search_results.html'**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <br><br>
    <h1> Assignment ID Search Results</h1>

    <p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

    {% if AssignmentsResults %}
        <ul>
            {% for assignments in AssignmentsResults %}
            <li>
                {{ assignments.id }}, {{ assignments.name }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No assignments matched your search criteria.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% endblock content %}
```

This is what I finally put together to include Products (shown below in the failed views.py and template).  But, it does not work.

This was the **FAILED VIEWS.PY**

```
    def search_form(request):
        return render(request, 'assignments/search_form.html')

    def search(request):
        if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
            q = request.GET['q']
            assign = Assignments.objects.filter(id__icontains=q)
            prod = Products.objects.filter(assignment__icontains=q)
            return render(request, 'assignments/search_results.html',
                {'AssignmentsResults': assign, 'query': q})
            return render(request, 'assignments/search_results.html',
                          'ProductsResults': prod, 'query': q)
        else:
            # if the query is empty, render the 'search_form html' template again.
            # display an error message in that template.  So, pass a template variable.
            # 'search_form html' will check for the 'error' variable
            return render(request, 'assignments/search_form.html', {'error': True})
```

This was the **FAILED TEMPLATE CODE 'search_results.html**

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}

    <br><br>
    <h1> Assignment ID Search Results</h1>

    <p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

    {% if AssignmentsResults %}
        <ul>
            {% for assignments in AssignmentsResults %}
            <li>
                {{ assignments.id }}, {{ assignments.name }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <p> These are the Products attached to the Assignment.</p>
        {% if ProductsResults %}
        <ul>
            {% for products in ProductsResults %}
            <li>
                {{ products.assignment }}, {{ products.name }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p> No products for this assignment exist.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No assignments matched your search criteria.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% endblock content %}
```

I have created the project by following 'Build a website with Django 2, updated for Django 2.2' by Nigel George. I have looked at several youtube instructional videos and read questions on stackoverflow. (These are only a couple.)

[How to combine two or more querysets in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-two-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view)

[Displaying a series of inline forms for a queryset of Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055947/displaying-a-series-of-inline-forms-for-a-queryset-of-django-models)

[Django: Add queryset to inlineformsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561378/django-add-queryset-to-inlineformsets)

[Django nested QuerySets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862838/django-nested-querysets)

[InlineFormSet with queryset of different model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269052/inlineformset-with-queryset-of-different-model)

However, none of them have been able to help me with my problem of presenting 2 separate queryset results on one form.

I'd certainly appreciate any suggestions and help provided.
Thanks

Comment: Oh boy... There are a lot of weird things out there, but okay. Basically what you want is to show Assignment and Product info in the search_results.html template, right?

Comment: @rvliscano - yes, you are correct.  I am wanting to show the Assignment queried and then all of the Products related to that Assignment in the search_results.html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's see. If you just want to display the information that it seems to be intended in search_results.html, I suggest you to refactor a little bit your query as follows.
(I will try to clean out the weird things (for example having two consecutive return statements) as much as I can to illustrate my point)

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse


def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if q:
        assignments_qs = Assignments.objects.filter(id__icontains=q) \
            .prefetch_related('productsfor_assignment')
        context_data = {'assignments': assignments_qs}
        return render(request, 'assignments/search_results.html', context_data)
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('search_form', kwargs={'error': True}))


def search_form(request, error=False):
    return render(request, 'assignments/search_form.html', {'error': error})
```

**search_results.html**

```
{% if assignments %}
    <ul>
        {% for assignment in assignments %}
            <li>
                {{ assignment.id }}, {{ assignment.name }}
            </li>                 
            {% if assignment.productsfor_assignment.exists %}
                <p> These are the Products attached to the Assignment.</p>
                <ul>
                {% for product in assignment.productsfor_assignment.all %}
                    <li>
                        {{ product.assignment }}, {{ product.name }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No assignments matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I think this is the best and the most similar way to achieve what you want considering what you currently have.

Comment: I noticed the changes in the views.py and search_results.html  Thank you.  However, I got an error.  I thought I might because I did not see where the table/model 'Products' was used in the code for 'products_set'. The parent table/model is 'Assignments' and the child table/model is 'Products'.  So the error I got was the following:  **AttributeError at /search/      Cannot find 'products_set' on Assignments object, 'products_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()**  Thank you for helping me with this problem.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry; I didn't note that you had defined a related_name attribute for the field assignment in the Products model. Let me edit and update the answer

Comment: Please note that I updated the name "products_set" for "productsfor_assignment" in both views.py and search_results.html

Comment: OMGOODNESS!!!!  You did it!  I now have an Assignments parent record and many Products children records displayed.  Thank You So Much!!!

Comment: I tried to upvote the answer but got the message from StackOverflow that I did not have a high enough reputation count (must have 15 points) to have my upvote displayed.  I am sorry the upvote does not show up.

Comment: I hate to bother you again, but something is wrong with this line of code in the views.py.  It is **return redirect(reverse('search_form', kwargs={'error': True}))**  I am getting the error **NoReverseMatch at /search/** and then the next line reads **Reverse for 'search_form' not found. 'search_form' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**  I tried to read about this NoReverseMatch error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390177/what-is-a-noreversematch-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)  However, I am a newbie and could not figure what to fix.  Can you help?  Should I repost?

Comment: You just need to replace the argument "search _form" inside the reverse function with the "name" attribute of the path you have assigned for that specific url in urls.py. I just put "search_form" there because I didn't know the actual name of it.